# ¿Cómo generar un texto con degradado y sombra con CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3

mi pregunta es sencilla, querría saber si existe alguna forma de rellenar la propiedad `content` con el contenido del elemento en cuestión.
Os dejo aquí un ejemplo:

```css
.saludo::before {
  content: same; /*Sé que este valor no existe, lo he puesto para que os hagais una idea de lo que busco*/
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="saludo">Hola</span>
```

Obviamente pregunto esto porque en la situación que lo requiero no me gustaría hacer una simple sombra corrída del texto.

El efecto que me gustaría conseguir sería algo como [esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dORE.jpg).

Y tampoco quisiera tener que escribir el contenido del elemento a mano (`content: "Hola"`), para que sea dinámico.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar por qué quieres hacer esto? Porque tener el mismo texto duplicado dos veces no es algo realmente útil, debe haber algún motivo por el que quieras hacerlo.  ¿Cuál es el objetivo final que quieres alcanzar?

Comment: Se trata de un [efecto](https://i.imgur.com/C1d63ag.jpg) en el texto, es simplemente curiosidad por aprender cosas nuevas.

Comment: La curiosidad es buena y esta pregunta es interesante. La cosa es que muchas veces este tipo de preguntas acaban siendo [problemas XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/250) y pensaba que igual éste podría ser uno de esos casos.

Comment: Espero que no, simplemente quería saber si se puede hacer mediante un valor de `content`, pero cualquier otra forma me sirve igual.

Comment: Igual se podría intentar con varios `text-shadows` pero creo que esa perspectiva sería imposible de conseguir sin pseudo-elementos.

Comment: Claro, además de que el fondo con degradado y las sombras parece que hacen conflicto, y el degradado se aplica sólo a la sombra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viendo en los comentarios el efecto que quieres conseguir te propongo una solución únicamente con CSS y sin utilizar el atributo `content` del pseudo-elemento before.

Para ello, necesitarás hacer uso de un `linear-gradient` que, combinado con las propiedades de CSS3`-webkit-background-clip: text` y `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent` te permitirá agregar un texto con degradado.

Además, le puedes agregar un borde al texto mediante la propiedad  `-webkit-text-stroke`.

Por último, podrás utilizar la propiedad `filter: drop-shadow` que actúa como `text-shadow` pero se la puedes aplicar al fondo.

```css
.textoPersonalizado{
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px #ff0080);
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p class="textoPersonalizado">ZONA DE RETOS</p>
```

Comment: Testeado en Google Chrome 65, Firefox 57 y Edge 41.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, muy interesante lo de filter, pero la razón por la cual no quería utilizar sombras es por la perspectiva, lo hice de esta [forma](https://thimbleprojects.org/elgolpista/453130/), como puedes ver hay dos pseudo-elementos, uno para el borde y otro para la "sombra" en perspectiva. Gracias a tu respuesta el borde podré ponerlo con filter.

Comment: Aunque el verdadero motivo de mi pregunta es poner el contenido de un elemento en la propiedad content del pseudo-elemento, el ejemplo de las sombras es simplemente para justificarlo con un caso práctico.

Comment: @Saul Perdona, edité tu pregunta ya que vi en los comentarios que lo que estabas buscando era eso y por focalizar el problema para el cual estaba destinado la pregunta pero puedes volver a editarla si estoy equivocado, por supuesto :P. No me fijé en que necesitabas un borde también, voy a intentar editar la respuesta para conseguir el efecto que buscas.

Comment: Vale, no hay problema, y gracias por todo.

Comment: @Saul Hay una propiedad que te permite añadirle borde al texto. Lo puedes ver **[aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/426t1osq/)**. ¿Es esto lo que buscas?

Comment: Oh, si, me sonaba que existía, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Me has solventado prácticamente todas las dudas, con respecto a lo de poner como valor de `content` el contenido dinámico de un elemento me temo que no es posible sin meterse en JS.

Comment: @Saul Sí, o con la opción de LPZadkiel utilizando un atributo extra en cada elemento.

Comment: Pero eso no se cambia dinámicamente, se tiene que actualizar en ambos sitios con cambio, es decir, dinámicamente no se puede sin JS.

Comment: @Saul Realmente el atributo `content` tampoco se puede modificar desde Javascript ya que no es parte del DOM.

Comment: Claro, pero si el contenido del atributo que pilla `content`

Comment: @Saul Sí, en ese caso si que se podría realizar con Javascript y por lo que he investigado creo que sería la única manera de hacerlo sin tener que poner los atributos a mano.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por todo :)

Answer (score 5):

Una solución que te puedo dar es utilizando para el contenido un atributo del mismo elemento, fuera de esta solución creo que lo mas apropiado es usar javascript

```css
.saludo::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="saludo" data-content="hola">hola</span>
```

Comment: Ya bueno, igualmente, no sería dinámico, y tendría que reescribir el contenido del elemento en el atributo, pero gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: claro si cambias el contenido del `span` tendrías que cambiar el contenido del atributo `data-content` para que funcione

Comment: Me temo que la única forma de hacerlo dinámico va a ser con JS

Comment: pienso que con js es la única forma